# Contracting Several nodes into one node

Tags: graphs

After finding the Strongly Connected Components of a graph and putting each SCC in a list, how i can contract each list of nodes into one node?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a programming question, which is offtopic here. Or is there a conceptual question you're having? (Community votes, please!)

Comment: In any case, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you want to build the graph of strongly connected components.

Traverse the edges of the graph once more. For every edge `(x,y)`:

- If `x` and `y` belong to the same SCC you do nothing.
- Else insert edge `(SCC[x],SCC[y])` in a new graph (the graph of strongly connected components).